# Run time error 91 on Collection

Tags: vba, excel

I have a range called "rng1" and first row is header. I would like to have a `collection` to store all the variable name. Given that there are 5 variables.

```
Sub Main()                           

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("rng1")
    Dim header As Collection

    For i = 1 To 5
        header.Add Item:=Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).Offset(0, i - 1).Value
    Next i

    End Sub
```

I able to display the variable name when I use the code `MsgBox Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).Offset(0,0).Value`

Comment: A quick search for "error 91" on this site yielded over 3000 results.... all involving an unassigned object reference. Your `header` is `Nothing` because you're not initializing it. Either declare it `As New Collection` or add a `Set header = New Collection` instruction.

Comment: On a related topic, if you decide to switch over to a Scripting.Dictionary to take advantage of its unique index you will have to use late binding or add **Microsoft.Scripting Runtime** to the project's references so that early binding will compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never set `header` to an object. When you declare `header` as a Collection, it instructs the compiler to reserve space for a `Collection` object but doesn't actually create one.  In order to instantiate the object, you need do something along the lines of:

```
Set header = New Collection
```

The language provides some shortcut syntax if you are creating an instance (as opposed to assigning from an existing one), and lets you combine the declaration and instantiation on one line:

```
Dim header As New Collection
```

So, the full code would look something like this:

```
Sub Main()                           

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("rng1")
    Dim header As New Collection

    For i = 1 To 5
        header.Add Item:=Cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).Offset(0, i - 1).Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: While answering the question, this comes off as little more than a comment. Expanding to show the revision to the code in place and possibly explaining Late Binding vs Early Binding even a tiny bit would have made this an excellent answer. @useR - see [Assigning an Object Reference to a Variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261365(v=vs.60).aspx) and [Object Variable Declaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cfwx51t1(v=vs.100).aspx) for more information.

Comment: @Jeeped - Editing now, but I'm not sure what this has to do with the binding model. Collections don't require either, and forgetting to add `CreateObject("Foo.Bar")` gets you the same error 91 as forgetting to add `Set baz = New Foo.Bar`.

Comment: @Jeeped - Not taken as a diss at all. ;-) About all I use late binding for is if I need to support multiple versions of Office. Your comment just made me realize that I have no idea how I would late bind a Collection even if I wanted to. I would have guessed `CreateObject("VBA.Collection")`, but it apparently isn't registered.

Comment: @Jeeped - Actually, early v. late binding is determined by whether you declare `Dim foo As FuBar` or `Dim foo As Object` and determines whether you are using the `IDispatch` or `IUnknown` COM interface. See [Using early binding and late binding in Automation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245115).